# Warn command Python 3.8

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I was trying to make a warn command but I failed so I ask here to people with more experience to help me

Thats my code (I dont have experience with json files)

I hope you can help me.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    warnsn = 0
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)

    warns[str(member)] = warnsn

    with open('warns.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(warns, f, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    warnsn = 0
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)

    warns.pop(str(member))

    with open('warns.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(warns, f, indent=4)

@client.command()
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, arg):
    warnsn = 0
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)

    warns[str(member)] = warnsn + 1

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(warns, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'{member} has been warned')

@client.command()
async def warns(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    warnsn = 0
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)

    warns[str(member)] = warns
    await ctx.send(f'{member} has {warnsn} warns')
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you don't have much experience with .json files use .txt files which are easier to use for you if .json is hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you define `warnsn` to 0 everytime, you just need to add 1 to the member in the JSON file

```py
@client.command()
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, arg):
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)

    warns[str(member)] += 1

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(warns, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'{member} has been warned')

@client.command()
async def warns(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)

    warnsn = warns[str(member)]
    await ctx.send(f'{member} has {warnsn} warns')
```

Comment: Thanks Poojan for the answer